# Tracking all incoming network traffic on a unbuntu server

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I would like to track all incoming traffic on a ubuntu web server, first by the address they are requesting and their ip address.

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks,
Ray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very open ended question.

If you are interested in recorded ALL traffic to saving it for future analysis, TCPDump is the way to go. File rotation and timestamps can be taken care of for you with the proper flags. http://www.tcpdump.org/

If you are looking for Source/Dest IP and port logging, netflow is more convenient as it takes less resources and disk space to manage. This can be accomplished through nProbe http://www.ntop.org/nProbe.html or nfcapd http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/nfcapd.1.html

You can always capture IP/port information from your router/firewall. This is probably the easiest.

Comment: thanks, that was a great answer. Will try the firewall approach first

Answer (score 0):

You can view packets with tcpdump or if you need a GUI with Wireshark.

Comment: Most web servers are remote, and it's hard to do the gui then, can you tcpdump remotely and view it in wireshark locally?

Comment: If all you're concerned about is web server request, can't you look at the request log ?

Comment: @NycCompSci Yes, you can dump it to file, scp it and view it on your machine.